# regular representation of algebras

Tags: abstract-algebra, representation-theory, lie-algebras

Let suppose we have universal enveloping algebra, what is the meaning of the notion of  the right regular representation of that? How can we determine the right regular representation of universal enveloping algebra?
Please give me a brief description of right regular representation of an algebra in general.

Comment: The right regular representation of an associative algebra is the action of the algebra on itself by right multiplication. In the enveloping algebra case, I've seen the terminology also used to describe the action of the Lie algebra on it's enveloping algebra by right multiplication.